# Docker - Passing env variable

Tags: docker

I have a docker file as below.

```
FROM docker.test.com/jdk/jdk1.8:latest

RUN mkdir -p /opt/test/emp

COPY application/emp-service.war /opt/test/emp/

ENV SERVER_SSL_TRUSTSTORE=/certs/cacert
ENV SERVER_SSL_KEYSTORE=/certs/emp-test.com.jks

CMD java -jar /opt/test/emp/emp-service.war --spring.config.location=file:/conf/application.properties -Dlogging.config=/conf/logback.xml
```

I am supposed to have the application.property,

> server.ssl.keyStore=PATH/TO/KEYSTORE

But, I dont want to hardcode this. Hence, having some path here and passing it as a volume while running docker as below.

> docker run -v LOCAL_PATH/emp-test.com.jks:/certs/emp-test.com.jks
>   test-service

But, still, I am getting the below error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource location must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:134) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getURL(ResourceUtils.java:131) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.configureSslKeyStore(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:301) ~[spring-boot-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.5.RELEASE]
```

I tried with -Dserver.ssl.keyStore in DockerFile as follows, but still the error is same.

> CMD java -jar /opt/test/emp/emp-service.war
>   --spring.config.location=file:/conf/application.properties -Dlogging.config=/conf/logback.xml -Dserver.ssl.keyStore=/certs/emp-test.com.jks

Am i missing anything?

I know, this can be done with Docker compose. But i just want o run using docker run.

Comment: Have you tried using `docker run -e LOCAL_PATH=VALUE ...` to embed your env var?

Comment: I dont get it. -e LOCAL_PATH=VALUE ???

Comment: Isnt all you want to do is pass an environment variable to your container without embedding it into the image, because your env var value changes from time to time?

Comment: I tried -e SERVER_SSL_KEYSTORE=PATH/TO/KEYSTORE in the docker run without havin ENV or -D in the docker image. But, still no luck.

Comment: If all you wish to do is pass that env var dynamically via `docker run`, try to do it again, this time launch `bash` and run `env`. Also, try to run `docker inspect -f='{{.Config.Env}}' <container_id>` and see the environment variables. Is it there?

Comment: Does the command line you provided (java -jar /opt/test/emp/emp-service.war --spring.config.location=file:/conf/application.properties -Dlogging.config=/conf/logback.xml -Dserver.ssl.keyStore=/certs/emp-test.com.jks) actually works when executed manually from within the container ? I'm wondering whether we are looking for an issue at the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

you can map the local volume(the one which which will have the ssl cert) to the container using VOLUME in the docker file and in the ENV for the docker file, pass in the location corresponding to the container.

Answer (score 0):

`docker run -e "foo=bar" ....` lets you set an environment variable inside the container. Your application can then read that env variable and fail if it is not provided. The same works also for compose, docker swarm and kubernetes.

See the [documentation of docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables)